# How do you say "numeral" in french for Siri to get numbers right?

Tags: siri, internationalization, voice-dictation

In english you would say "Hey Siri, Play Led Zeppelin `*numeral*` 4" in order for Siri to detect that *4* is a number rather that a word like "for".

Do you know the keyword that replaces "numeral" when Siri speaks french?

(I tried "numéro", "nombre", "numérique", "numéral"... none seem to work)

Comment: Do you have a specific example of when this would be useful? What French numbers are homophones with other French words that it throws Siri off?

Comment: Do you 'speak' to Siri en français?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes, my Siri is configured in french. It understands and speaks french.

Comment: @BooleanCheese Here are examples: "Joue la piste 1" is understood as "Joue la piste hein" (Siri: ne trouve pas la piste hein). 2 is recognized as "d'eux", somehow "3" is understood as... "sept", "9" as "neuf" (="new"), etc.

Comment: Do you have a srong accent ?

Comment: @Solar Mike : non, native french. btw numbers are an issue in english as well, that is why it is recommended to add "numeral" in order for Siri to get it right.

Comment: Only asked as I was in Lyon, but when visiting Marseille... and yes I do wonder how Siri will get on with a glaswegian accent or dialect for example.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is [in the official Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/HT202584), you should say "numérotation quatre" to input "4".

Comment: Judging by your link, it seems like now it’s “numérique” : Dites « Numérique » afin d’activer le format numérique pour la phrase suivante.